# Attempting to solve “how old is your dog in human years?” in python on coursera

Tags: python

I keep running into a problem that I am unable to understand. Can someone please help me understand what it means. just need a hint if that's ok. I have attempted to google the error I have attempted asking my coworkers and my last resort is the stack overflow community. so far the only thing I was able to make out is the my print is incorrectly formatted but how I cannot understand.
Here is my code:

```
def calculator():
    age = input("Please enter dog age ")
    d_age = 0
    try:
        d_age = float(age)
        if d_age <= 0:
            raise NameError
        elif d_age >= 5:
            d_age = ((d_age - 5) * 7 + 36)
          
        elif d_age <= 1:
            d_age = (d_age * 15)
            
        elif d_age <= 2:
            d_age = (d_age * 12)
            
        elif d_age <= 3:
            d_age = (d_age * 9.3)
           
        elif d_age <= 4:
            d_age = (d_age * 8)
            
        elif d_age <= 5:
            d_age = (d_age * 7.2)

    except ValueError:
        print("entered age is invalid!")
    except NameError:
        print("Please enter a non negative age")
    print("The given dog age", age, "is", round(d_age, 2), "in human years.")

calculator()
```

Comment: Your `if` statements are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: I'm sorry can you explain what you mean?

Comment: i think i understand for every instance of my if statemts i need the print statement

Comment: No, you need a correct logic.  Get paper and pencil and run through you code manually.

Comment: The error you have is pretty self explanatory… you are calling the `calculator()` function with no argument and it expects a value it can place into the `age` parameter. Also, your print statement is only in one of your `if` conditions. You should remove the spacing in front of the print statement so it is on the same level with the `if` statements, then it will print after it goes through all the `if`s.

Comment: but I do have an argument in the call of calculator, I wrote calculator(age) at the very bottom of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Previously, if you inputted "1" `if d_age <= 1:` would be true, and `if d_age <= 2:` would be true, and so on so forth. This only allows one condition to be true which gives the correct answer.

Your second sneakier issue is that the course is assuming your `calculator` function does not take any arguments, but rather calls `input` from inside the function.

```
def calculator():
    age = input("Please enter dog age ")
    d_age = 0
    try:
        d_age = float(age)
        if d_age <= 0:
            raise NameError
        elif d_age >= 5:
            d_age = ((d_age - 5) * 7 + 36)
          
        elif d_age <= 1:
            d_age = (d_age * 15)
            
        elif d_age <= 2:
            d_age = (d_age * 12)
            
        elif d_age <= 3:
            d_age = (d_age * 9.3)
           
        elif d_age <= 4:
            d_age = (d_age * 8)
            
        elif d_age <= 5:
            d_age = (d_age * 7.2)

    except ValueError:
        print("entered age is invalid!")
    except NameError:
        print("Please enter a non negative age")
    print("The given dog age", age, "is", round(d_age, 2), "in human years.")

calculator()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248073/discussion-on-answer-by-jrose-attempting-to-solve-how-old-is-your-dog-in-human).